# git extensions pull error info: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@

Tags: git

When I used git extensions on windows to pull a repo, a error info: "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@" was return.

Meanwhile I can use git command line "git pull origin" to pull the repo. It seems there was something wrong with git extensions configuration, anyone can help me correct this error?

Answer (score 13):

Set your Git Extensions ssh client to be "OpenSSH" instead of "PuTTy".

You can configure it under: Tools -> Settings -> Git Extensions -> SSH -> "Specify which SSH client to use":

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The other possible solution is if you use Putty Pageant, and you have your keys stored in Pageant to handle the authentication, check that Pageant is running.  If you have restarted your machine Pageant might not be running and the authentication will fail with this error.  If you restart your Pageant and make sure that your Keys are added this will fix your error.

Comment: This actually was the problem for me. I ran Pageant and I saw it was missing my private key (ppk), so I added it and ran the git command again, it worked like charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like using putty/ssh with Git. I had this problem because when I was adding a new remote I failed to put the protocol first:

`git remote add <remotename> ssh://<username>@<hostname>:<port>/<project>.git`